# data pseudonymization in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, data-masking

I am trying get the PII data from postgreSQL table. But I can't display the raw data.
How to Pseudonymize the data while fetching(select) it from postgreSQL database?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create (pseudo)anonymized views for tables, and select from those. As for anonymization techniques, that depends on data, you can use regex replaces and md5 very easily in postgres.